# Admin-on-Rest ReferenceField not rendering properly

Tags: admin-on-rest

I don't get ReferenceField to work properly as it only shows the progress bar "spinning" for the 'firstName' field.

I can successfully use the examples with data from  https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ to work with the simpleRest client but not with my own API end points. I see the GET_LIST request - response and then the related GET_MANY response with the Owner data but the reference field labeled 'User' doesn't render.

One of the differences in structure of API endpoints is that the reference returned in my API is fully qualified following this structure "resource:io.mydomain.#"

But since the second API call is fired off and data returned it seems that this doesn't matter. At this point I need some pointers to where to go next...

```
//App.js
const App = () => (
  <Admin dashboard={Dashboard} theme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)} title="Admin" authClient={authClient} restClient={restClient}>
      <Resource name="Asset" list={AssetList} label="Assets" />
      <Resource name="Owner" list={UserList}  label="Users"  />
      <Resource name="AssetTitle" list={AssetTitleList}  label="Ownership" />
 </Admin>

//users.js
 export const UserList = (props) => (
     <List title="All Users" {...props}>
         <Datagrid>
             <TextField source="id" />
             <TextField source="firstName" />
             <TextField source="lastName" />
             <TextField source="mobile" />
             <EmailField source="email" />
               <EditButton />
         </Datagrid>
     </List>
 );

 //titles.js
 export const AssetTitleList = (props) => (
     <List title="All Titles..." {...props}>
         <Datagrid>
           <TextField source="id" />
           <ReferenceField label="User" source="owner" reference="Owner" >
                          <TextField source="firstName" />
           </ReferenceField>
           <TextField source="information" />
         </Datagrid>
     </List>
 );

//AssetTitle API returns
[{"$class":"io.mydomain.AssetTitle",
"id":"12345",
"owner":"resource:io.mydomain.Owner#11111",
"asset":"resource:io.mydomain.Asset#991",
"information":""}]

//Owner API returns
[{"$class":"io.mydomain.Owner",
"firstName":"Joe",
"lastName":"Doe",
"email":"joe@doe.com",
"mobile":"",
"id":"11111"}]
```

[Screenshot of Referencefield rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ykhz.png)

Comment: Can you see anything in the console ? Do titles **always** have an owner ?  If not, try adding `allowEmpty` on your `ReferenceField`

Comment: yes, title will always have an owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to clean the data returned from your API in your `restClient`.

I see that the `owner` field for the `title` resource is `resource:io.mydomain.Owner#11111`. However, the `id` field of the `owner` resource is `11111`.

You'll have to implement your own `restClient` and "clean" all known ids such as the `owner` field so that they only contains the id. See the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#writing-your-own-rest-client) about implementing your own rest client.

Comment: ok, thanks, so in the convertHTTPResponseToREST method, in case type of GET_MANY_REFERENCE I could trim the response before its returned?

Comment: By cleaning up the response carrying the fully qualified reference field as suggested, in the convertHTTPResponseToREST method - case GET_MANY_REFERENCE, the problem is solved.

Comment: You'll probably have to do this for the other verbs too