# <ReferenceField> in <List> only works on second request - Admin On Rest

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

When loading a list of Venues with related a Market resource the initial load shows an infinitely loading progressbar similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905033/admin-on-rest-referencefield-not-rendering-properly), except for one thing; it shows the market properly in the list on the second render.

The requests are identical on both renders.

[first render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOFuS.png) | [second render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ppYp.png)

What might be happening here?

**Here's the view component**

```
export const VenueList = (props) => (
  <List {...props}>
    <Datagrid>
      <TextField source="name" />
      <ReferenceField label="market" source="market" reference="markets">
        <TranslatableField source="title" />
      </ReferenceField>
      <EditButton basePath="/venues" />
      <DeleteButton basePath="/venues" />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

**And here's TranslatableInput**

```
export const TranslatableField = ({ data, source, record = {}, elStyle, locale }) => {
  const translation = getTranslationByLocale(data || record[source], locale);
  return (<span style={elStyle}>{translation}</span>);
};
```

Comment: Can you post your admin component with its resources please ?